# How to install new crontab?

Tags: linux, cron, centos

How to install new crontab using linux cent os?
I was runed crontab -r by mistekaly, so file was deleted.
If i create new file usinng crontab -e and try to save and exit then below error return is return:

```
errors in crontab file, can't install.
```

How to create new crontab file?

Comment: There is an error in the crontab file, but we can't see it.

Comment: But file was deleted by crontab -r.

Answer (score -1, accepted):

From [install crontab](https://blog.inticol.com/2013/03/install-crontab-on-centos-6.html) the crontab package in CentOS is vixie-cron. Hence, do install it with:

Install the package and dependencies

```
#yum install vixie-cron
```

Enable the package on boot and start

```
# /sbin/chkconfig crond on

# /etc/init.d/crond start
```